# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Partial Views in 1 View Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am having trouble dealing with user registration in ASP.NET MVC3 Model Binding.

Basically, I have a ViewModel that consists of UserDetails (name, identification, dob and other things) and a reusable ViewModel, Address.

So, UserDetails class will also carry an Address class.

Then, I created a partial view with model binding to Address ViewModel so that this too can be reusable.

In view, this is what I did: @Html.Partial("CommonAddress")

However, upon creation of user, I was unable to retrieve Address at all as it is still null. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your address model to the partial just like

```
@Html.Partial("CommonAddress", Model.Address)
```

If you do not have a model yet, pass a default/empty model from your Controller Edit action (the one that handles the GET HTTP request) to the view.

Comment: I can pass it in if my case is Edit. What if it's create? There is no model yet. Doing so will end up with Null Reference Exception.

Comment: Create a empty model and pass that to the view, I changed my answer according to your comment

Comment: Hm, this would also pose a problem because in my UserDetails ViewModel, I have a property of bool type called isActive. If I create an empty object, it would automatically assign as false in the view. Sorry, I'm quite noobish when it comes to MVC. This is my first project.

Comment: The question you have to answer yourself is if you need distinct view models for Edit and Create UserDetails.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping there could be one universal solution to the problem whereby the engine would handle Partials much like UserControls in webforms. Guess I was wrong. So a more appropriate way to do this is to flatten the view instead. 

So in my main View, instead of @Html.Partial("CommonAddress"), I'll take all UI out from the partial and place in my main view. When I do model binding, I'd just do @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Model.Address.street1)

Am I correct?

Comment: No not really if you have a UserDetails ViewModel and a property Address in it everything should work perfect. The IsActive property could be a problem in case this property is not editable in the Create view. In case it is - everything works! Just pass the UserDetails.Address to the partial. Perhaps you should open a new stackoverflow question describing the general problem not just the problem with the partial :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it too clear. The problem I had with instantiating an empty object in the controller and pass to view is that by default, isActive is of bool type and is instantiated as false, thereby, in the view (RadioButtons) it is automatically selected as false. Perhaps I could make isActive nullable but it's kinda against business logic. I'm quite stubborn at times :D I'd like to thank you for your help, Saintedlama. But it'd be great if you can further reply to this.